# How do i prevent a primary key from accepting random value?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to programming. Please pardon my novice question.

I created a table in myql workbench,then I made one of the header primary key , but if I insert a random value to Mt primary key column it still accepts any value.

Please how can I prevent this?
Thanks.

Comment: Random like [4](https://xkcd.com/221/)? Can you show the table definition `show create tablename` as text by editing your question. The column type shows the range of values accepted.

Comment: Well of course it does as long as it's not a duplicate...what logic would you like to apply to restrict it?